# $L_2$-norm representation of the function

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, polynomials, special-functions, wavelets

Let
$$
f^{\alpha}_+(x)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha+1)}\sum_{k\ge 0}(-1)^k{\alpha+1 \choose k}(x-k)^{\alpha}_+,
$$
where $\alpha > -\frac 12$(see for reference http://bigwww.epfl.ch/publications/unser9901.pdf).

I am wondering if one can get nice representation of $L_2$-norm of the function $f^{\alpha}(x)$, namely
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(f^{\alpha}_+(x))^2dx.
$$

(Here $y^{\alpha}_+=\max(0, y)^{\alpha}$ is a one-sided power function).

Thank you.

Comment: $f_+^\alpha$ doesn't belong to $L^2$

Comment: It is. Function $f^{\alpha}$ is a fractional spline. It was proved by M. Uhser http://bigwww.epfl.ch/publications/unser9901.pdf , that it belongs to $L_2$.

Comment: When, I tried to plot this function it turns out to tend to minus infinity. And if your question raised from this paper,  why don't you put this reference in your question?

Comment: What is the meaning of $\binom{\alpha+1}{k}$  and $(x-k)^{\alpha}$?

Comment: What is the meaning of "representation of $L_{2}-$norm"?

Comment: For the record, I attempted to do this using the Fourier transform of $f_+^\alpha$ given in the paper (equation 3.1, page 52). Spending a couple of minutes messing around with it in Mathematica, I couldn't get a nice expression. Basically, I messed around with $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \bigg({(1-e^{ix})(1-e^{-ix})\over x^2}\bigg)^{\alpha+1}\ dx$$
This seems like it could be tractable, but it might not be.

Comment: @Kuashik, $\big({u\atop v}\big)={\Gamma(u+1)\over\Gamma(v+1)\Gamma(u-v+1)}$ and $x^\alpha_+=\cases{x^\alpha& $x\ge 0$\cr 0& else}$ (this is defined in the OP).

Comment: Sorry B R : I know $x^n$ where $n$ is an integer, $x^{\alpha}$ for $x>0, \alpha \in \mathbb R$

Comment: @Kuashik, it's always ok to ask for definitions of things. And $x_+^\alpha$ is certainly not a standard thing, unless you've studied a bit about distributions.

Comment: Cross-posted to MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/97141/l-2-norm-representation